# How to configure RewriteAppender with multiple AppenderRefs in a properties file?

Tags: arrays, configuration, log4j2, properties-file

I am trying to use the `RewriteAppender` to make mods to the `LogEvent` and then pass it along to several other appenders. (My environment requires all configurations to use properties files.)

In looking at the code in `PropertiesConfigurationBuilder` methods `processRemainingProperties()` and `createComponent`, it is not clear how to configure this if it is even possible at all.

The documentation (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#configuration-with-properties) has an example that includes:

```
logger.app.appenderRef.$1.ref = stdout
logger.app.appenderRef.$2.ref = file
```

My latest attempt to configure this array was this: (note the plural "appenderRefs" since that is the plugin builders parameter name)

```
# added for error "No type attribute for component appenderRefs"
appender.rewrite.appenderRefs.type = AppenderRef 
appender.rewrite.appenderRefs.stdout.type = AppenderRef
appender.rewrite.appenderRefs.stdout.ref = stdout
appender.rewrite.appenderRefs.file.type = AppenderRef
appender.rewrite.appenderRefs.file.ref = file
```

I was expecting the `appenderRefs` RewriteAppender property to be set to an array with two elements but I get the following ConfigurationException:

```
Arguments given for element RewriteAppender are invalid: field 'appenderRefs' has invalid value '[Lorg.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;@740fb309'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, the **general** rule used to transform a set of properties into an XML tree transforms:

```
<parentPrefix>.<id1>.type = Component
<parentPrefix>.<id1>.foo = bar
<parentPrefix>.<id1>.<id2>.type = SubComponent
<parentPrefix>.<id1>.<id2>.bar = baz
<parentPrefix>.<id1>.<id3>.type = SubComponent
```

into the subtree:

```xml
<Component foo="bar">
  <SubComponent bar="baz"/>
  <SubComponent/>
</Component>
```

So assuming `appender.rewrite` is the prefix of the `Rewrite` appender, you can use:

```
appender.rewrite.stdout.type = AppenderRef
appender.rewrite.stdout.ref = stdout
appender.rewrite.file.type = AppenderRef
appender.rewrite.file.ref = file
```

Why does the example from the documentation work?

Beyond the general rule (expressed in the [`processRemainingProperties`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/32075af9323dce1bbb8f66922aa2cccbb46cd4fd/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/properties/PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java#L344-L360) method), some *sub-trees* have **special** rules. For example the properties that start with `logger.` are parsed by [`createLogger`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/32075af9323dce1bbb8f66922aa2cccbb46cd4fd/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/properties/PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java#L253-L291), which accepts the syntax you found in the doc:

```
logger.app.appenderRef.$1.ref = stdout
logger.app.appenderRef.$2.ref = file
```

but does **not** accept:

```
logger.app.$1.type = AppenderRef
logger.app.$1.ref = stdout
logger.app.$2.type = AppenderRef
logger.app.$2.ref = file
```

**Remark**: the `3.x` version of Log4j will feature a new [`log4j-config-properties`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-config-properties) with coherent mapping rules provided by [`jackson-dataformat-properties`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/2.17/properties). Under these new rules you'll be able to write:

```
Appenders.Rewrite.AppenderRef[1].ref = stdout
Appenders.Rewrite.AppenderRef[2].ref = file
```

Comment: ... but I did have one small comment/question...
It seems that the mapping of properties to actual builder `@PluginElement` is strictly based on the `type` attribute. So, let's say I had an appender that I wanted to configure with a `Layout` for left-to-right message publishing and another `Layout` for right-to-left message publishing, then I would actually need to create a whole new plugin type.

Comment: Yes, sub components are injected by type. You can however have a field of type `Layout[]`. The only catch is that the properties format is unsorted...